# Parse Cloud for Querying Database with Sorting Order

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I am new to JavaScript. I am writing a cloud code in parse.com. I have a field called index(Number type) in USER Class in database. I am getting error Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in main.js:6

the code i am using is

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  // Check if the user added a pin in the last minute
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.ascending(“index”);

  // Count the number of pins
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
if(results.length > 0){
     var object = results[0];

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
    response.success();
}
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error('Oups something went wrong.');
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me out ?

P.S its working fine if I replace "index" with "createdAt" in query.ascending(key);

Comment: Replace “ with " or ' and you should be good to go ;-) `query.ascending('index');`

Comment: @BjörnKaiser thank you very much, so if its number then 'key' and if its type is string then "key", am I right ??

Comment: No the error was that you had ill-formatted quotes. " is not the same as “ or ”. " and ' are interchangeable.